# UIButton Hiding in Skscene Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am making an app that will switch to a different screen when it reaches a random number of clicks on the screen. I am using a button that is hidden to segue to the end screen. When I hide the button in the `viewDidLoad`, it will not appear when called in another method after it reaches the required number of randomized clicks Why does the hidden button not become visible?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    Final.hidden = YES;
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsNodeCount = NO;
    SKScene * scene = [BellPepperMyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
    [skView presentScene:scene];
}

-(IBAction)GoToNewScreen:(id)sender {      
    Final.hidden = false;
}

-(void)goToEndScreen{  
    [self GoToNewScreen:nil];
}
```

Comment: Maybe a suggestion, you could set the whole view for a tap recognizer so you do not need a button. Or do they need to "Click" the hidden button sometimes while searching for it like in a "Find the hidden button" game and click it 5 times?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Final is a UIButton, there are a few things you want to be aware of.  First is that you should be setting Final.alpha = 0, and not Final.hidden = YES.  This can cause problems with it receiving touch events.

You should also make sure that you have the order of the views setup right.  If you want to makes sure that the button is visible you can call [self.view bringSubviewToFront:Final].